# Show The Command Line of Valgrind Used in Eclipse CDT

Tags: profile, command-line-arguments, valgrind, memcheck

I'm using valgrind for profiling/memchecking my application in Eclipse CDT (Indigo).

After profiling it with memcheck in Eclipse, I found two "possibly lost"s (both from libraries that are out of my control).  So I want to add them to my suppressions list.

I then ran the same binary using valgrind in command line:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --gen-suppressions=all myapp --arg1 --arg2
```

To my supprise, the two "possibly losts"s are not showing up. (if they show up, I could just add them to my suppressions list in Eclipse)

I'm wondering what options are passed to valgrind in Eclipse profiling.  But I don't know how to show the command line of valgrind when profiling in Eclipse.

Please help me out. Thanks.

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself.  Actually, it's very simple, and I don't know why I could not think of this before:

On the command line:

```
plee@pleeUbuntu:~$ ps -ef | grep valgrind
plee     24548 17479 91 12:43 ?        00:00:14 /usr/bin/valgrind.bin --tool=memcheck -q --log-file=/home/plee/EclipseCDT-IndigoWorkspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.linuxtools.valgrind.launch/valgrind_%p.txt --trace-children=no --child-silent-after-fork=yes --run-libc-freeres=yes --demangle=yes --num-callers=20 --error-limit=yes --show-below-main=no --max-stackframe=2000000 --dsymutil=yes --suppressions=/home/plee/valgrind_suppressions.supp --leak-check=yes --show-reachable=no --leak-resolution=low --freelist-vol=10000000 --workaround-gcc296-bugs=no --partial-loads-ok=no --undef-value-errors=yes --track-origins=no MyProgramBinary --arg1 --arg2
```